# Dynamic Image displaying - javascript wrong url reading

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am writing the ASP.Net Core View, where I need to display dynamically img.
I am passing the `@Model.AvatarUrl,` which is generated in Controller, to View, and displaying it as

```
defaultPreviewContent: '<img src="\\@Model.AvatarUrl" alt="Your Avatar" style="width:160px">',
```

The problem is, that my urls are generated randomly, and I got link of @Model.AvatarURL as:

```
   "\\Uploads\\n2wrcbyx.buf.jpg"
```

Now, the browser does not want to display it, because it reads as `"\Uploads2wrcbyx.buf.jpg"`, so I am guessing that \n special character is read and my url is bad.
How to fix that? Change in the `@Model.AvatarUrl` is really not an option, because it would cause a lot of problems.

Comment: had you tried using slash "/" instead of backslash "\" ?

Comment: Yes, forward slash works, but what I wanted is work with backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your string being unescaped twice, one at server side and one at client side. What the browser gets from "\\Uploads\\n2wrcbyx.buf.jpg" it's "\Uploads\n2wrcbyx.buf.jpg" and then \n is interpreted as new line.

What worked for me was replacing "\\" by "\\\\" in the view.

In my model

```
public string AvatarUrl { get { return "\\Uploads\\n2wrcbyx.buf.jpg"; } }
```

In my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = {
      defaultPreviewContent: '<a href="\\@Model.AvatarUrl.Replace("\\", "\\\\")">hover</a>'
    };
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = model.defaultPreviewContent;
</script>
```

Finally the url for the link looks like

```
http://uploads/n2wrcbyx.buf.jpg
```

If you want to produce url from server root using Razor it's:

```
defaultPreviewContent: '<a href="@Url.Content(@Model.AvatarUrl.Replace("\\", "\\\\"))"
```

And you get:

```
http://localhost:7669/Uploads/n2wrcbyx.buf.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be good answer, however, I change my implementation to use finally //, so I do not have a problem.